# iPad app screen dimensions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I built an iPad app.I do not want to use AutoLayout.I would like to handle position of UIElements according to view size.

I try to take screen dimensions with this code:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

But when i test the app on iPad simulator and iPad Retina simulator i always get the same result and some of UIElements disappear. I want to take screen dimensions to position my elements in the right point.But i do not get different bounds for iPad and iPad Retina simulators.

In iPhone app i got screen dimensions and i check if height is equals to 480 or not and i handle position of my elements.

In iPad how can i do this?

Comment: There is difference in resolution, not height and width of iPad Retina and non-Retina screens.

Comment: So how can i position my UIElements according to iPad device? In iPhone apps i reached this with the code above. In iPad app some UIElements disappear when i run the app in iPad Retina simulator.

Comment: The Retina screen having the resolution just double the existing height and width of iPad. You have to give the assests, just double of existing.

Comment: Position of all elements will be same always for Retina or Non Retina iPad.....There are only resolution difference i both device not in Height or width....

Comment: Yes i know that, but when i run the app in Retina simulator the elements disappear...

Comment: you use image on elements ?????

Comment: No.Simple buttons that have been positioned in Storyboard. I want to take the device dimensions and position them programmatically.

Comment: Why don't you want to use autolayout?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference with the positioning.. The positions will be the same.. irrespective of whether it is retina or not..

Comment: will you show your code which you use to set position of elements ????

Comment: Both have same dimension no need to update UI Element Position.The Retina screen having the resolution just double the non-Retina. Only place double resolution images for Retina

Answer (score 0):

iPad and iPad retina have different resolutions. But their physical screen size is the same. Thats the reason why you get the same value for both.

Comment: please see my comment above.

Comment: @hoya21 it's not about us having to read your comments to get an update to your question you should be updating your question. So based on your original question this is correct.

Comment: @Popeye is it ok now?